# About Database Encryption in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'am evaluating OrientDB for a SaaS-CRM project and really expect to use it.
Since data security is a key factor, I'd like the OrientDB development team to answer my questions.

1. In version 2.2, is it possible to encrypt clusters/databases by **orientjs api**( and/or sql api, db functions), and totally independent of java api? if true, then how can I do?
2. Encrypting fields/attributes of records is on your schedule? If so,When will come to release?

If I do not express clearly, pls forgive me:-)
Many thanks.

Hanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you mean encrypt records? OrientDB provides encryption at
   storage level, but once records are sent to node.js driver, they are
   decrypted. If you want such encryption it's not supported out of the box, sorry. You can still use SSL to encrypt data of your connection in case and this is provided out of the box.
2. It's a feature request, but it's not on our roadmap for the next
   year unless we find a sponsor for it.