# Is it possible to create an encrypted database in OrientDB 2.2 via OrientJS?

Tags: orientdb

I have a need to dynamically create databases in code via the OrientJS driver.  I see an example of how to create an encrypted DB using the Java API but nothing in the JS api/OrientJS.

Comment: Hi Mike, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738585/about-database-encryption-in-orientdb) answer about the encryption in OrientJS. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not available through remote OrientDB binary protocol, so you cannot do that via JS but also Java API and Console if you use remote protocol.