# Can a OrientDB database be completely encrypted?

Tags: orientdb

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738585/about-database-encryption-in-orientdb) an orientdb database can be encrypted by record, presumably on the application layer. Can a database be completely encrypted at creation time, or can an existing database be encrypted at the driver level? Or should application and storage level security be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an encrypted database using either the console or through the Java API. To create an encrypted database, use the -encryption option through the `CREATE DATABASE` command. However, before you do so, you must set the encryption key by defining the storage.encryptionKey value through the `CONFIG` command.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Database-Encryption.html

Hope it helps

Regards